# Basic grid using boostrap does not work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to twitter-bootstrap, I've created a simple page(According to the [doc](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem) ) as a follow:
 But not working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> GLSI/GTR ISI</title>
    <!--    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> -->

            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
            <link href="css/navbar-fixed-top.css" rel="stylesheet" />

            <script src="js/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
            <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>



    <div class="row">

           <div class="span4">
               a
              </div>   

          <div class="span4">
               b

              </div>

          <div class="span4">
               c
              </div>

    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Something is missing ?

Comment: Why are you including both the `bootstrap.min.css` and `bootstrap.css`? They are the same thing, only one is minified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a container div around your row:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
            a
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            b
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            c
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also you don't need to include the normal and minified version of the theme and bootstrap css files. Just use the minified version.

You may not even need to bother with the theme file if you are not actually using anything from it.

Comment: I would think the theme would need to come after the main bootstrap css as well, if it is overriding some of the default styles.